# How to init typeahead on new created input?

Tags: jquery, typeahead

I'm looking for a while to make it works.

This is my last try.

I have this **html** :

```
<td>
   <input type="text" value="" class="typeahead" style="width: 310px" autocomplete="off" data-provide="typeahead" />
   <input type="hidden" value="" class="delivery" name="delivery[]" />
</td>
```

And on **JS** side, I have this :

```
$(".typeahead").on("create", function() {
    $(this).typeahead({
        limit : 20,
        remote : {
            url: '/ajax/places/?query=',
            replace: function(url, encodedUrl) {

              return url + encodedUrl + '&categorySon=5';
            },
            filter: function (result) {

                var list = [];

                result.aaData.map(function (item) {

                    list.push({

                        value: item.name + ' (' + item.code + ')',
                        id: item.id

                    });

                });

                return list;
            }
        }
    }).bind('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum) {
        $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='hidden']").val(datum.id);
    });
});
```

So, when I add dynamically an other input typeahead it doesn't works (even on the one create on loading of the page, it works fine with basic $(".typeahead).typeahead...)

thanks a lot for your help !

Edit on 09-17 :

For now the suggest list works, but the `bind('typeahead:selected,...` did not

This is my code edited :

```
function initPlaceTypeahead() {
    $(".placeTypeahead").typeahead({
        limit : 20,
        remote : {
            url: '/ajax/places/?query=',
            replace: function(url, encodedUrl) {

              return url + encodedUrl + '&categorySon=5';
            },
            filter: function (result) {

                var list = [];

                result.aaData.map(function (item) {

                    list.push({

                        value: item.name + ' (' + item.code + ')',
                        id: item.id

                    });

                });

                return list;
            }
        }
    }).bind('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum) {
        $(this).parent().parent().find("input[class='delivery']").val(datum.id);
    });
}


$('#addCity').click(function() {

     var lastFilled = $("#delivery tr input[type='hidden']").last().val();

     if (lastFilled === '') {

         alert("La ville est obligatoire.");
         $("#delivery tr input[class='typeahead tt-query']").last().focus();

     } else {

        $("#delivery tr").eq(1).clone().find("input").each(function() {
            $(this).val('')
                   .attr('placeholder', '');
        }).end().appendTo("#delivery");

        $("#delivery tr a").removeClass("resetCity");
        $("#delivery tr a").addClass("delCity");

        $("#delivery tr").eq(2).clone().find("input").each(function() {
            $(this).val('').attr('placeholder', 'Informations Complémentaires');
        }).end().appendTo("#delivery");

        initPlaceTypeahead();

     }
});
```

Comment: 'create' is not a standard event supported by jQuery. So, unless the typeahead plugin has added that event, jQuery won't recognise it. Instead, in the segment of code where you are dynamically adding the input, you'll need to call `$('.new-element').typeahead()`

Comment: There is no solution to "listen" on create new element event ?

Comment: I Did this but `.bind('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum) {
        $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='hidden']").val(datum.id);
    })` seems not working

Comment: Should I give more information in order to have some helps ? thx :)

Comment: I edited all modifications I did thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem !

I made this in the typeahead:selected event :
`$(this).closest("tr").find("input[class='delivery']").val(datum.id);`

it seems that the parent level be different ...